# like i having table1 in that amount column is there but how much amount is there in that column i dont know to display top 10 high amounts

Tags: sql

like i having table 1 in that amount column is there but how much amount is there in that column i dont know to display top 10 high amounts using sql

Comment: Hi, Please provide more detail and what you have tried.

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 amount from India_base.accounts_balance_transactions order by amount desc i have tryed like this but it showing error

Comment: what to do pls ?

Answer (score 1):

As the question misses some details,

SELECT TOP 10 Amounts FROM India_Base
ORDER BY AMOUNTS DESC

Comment: error is showing

Comment: my table name is india_base in that amount column i want to display 10 high amounts

Comment: SELECT TOP(10) Amounts FROM India_base ORDER BY Amounts DESC

Comment: no error only showing function top not registerd